# Golang producing weired result for bitwise not operations

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

```
package main

import "fmt"

func SingleZeroBitAtRightMostOneBitPosition(n int) int {
    return ^n | (n - 1)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(SingleZeroBitAtRightMostOneBitPosition(128))
    // -129 is producing instead of 127!!

}
```

128   -> 10000000 
^128  -> 01111111 
127   -> 01111111 
result should be 127 (01111111)
but golang producing -129!!
Anyone can explain!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: int is 32b or 64b, not 8b (https://go.dev/ref/spec#Numeric_types)

Answer (score 0):

This would output the result you expect (127):

```
func SingleZeroBitAtRightMostOneBitPosition(n uint8) uint8 {
    return ^n | (n - 1)
}
```

Note that I'm using an unsigned 8 bit integer; `int8` will not work because, as [mentioned in the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Numeric_types), `int8` is "the set of all signed  8-bit integers (-128 to 127)" (which does not include 128).

As per the comment the main issue here is that `int` will be either 32 or 64 bits; lets work through the operation with a 32 bit int (the end result will be the same with 64 bits):

```
128  00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000

^128 11111111 11111111 11111111 01111111
127  00000000 00000000 00000000 01111111
OR   11111111 11111111 11111111 01111111
```

So the result is -129 (`int` is signed and the most common method of representing negatives is [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).